# Regtest: address is still at zero after sending some bitcoins

Tags: python, regtest

I'm trying to send some btc to an address in Regtest mode:

the address where I want to send is: `mjeoXvBnD4DtZumeSJEjNJfLb4RrhpbH1H`

```
$  bitcoin-cli -regtest -rpcuser=bitcoinrpc -rpcpassword=Alice -rpcport=16591 sendtoaddress mjeoXvBnD4DtZumeSJEjNJfLb4RrhpbH1H 5.00
9caca4f88c6bf727f6e8599fc1012867561ff7ef34412ef1fc70457fadf08e0b
```

I generate a new block:

```
$  bitcoin-cli -regtest -rpcuser=bitcoinrpc -rpcpassword=Alice -rpcport=16591 generate 1
[
    "5851b3adfd810480e53fbb5dab1ce4967a50f072a5a7abe054f114839ea3501e"
]
```

Then, I check the amount of btc inside the address:

```
$  bitcoin-cli -regtest -rpcuser=bitcoinrpc -rpcpassword=Alice -rpcport=16591 getreceivedbyaddress mjeoXvBnD4DtZumeSJEjNJfLb4RrhpbH1H 
0.00000000
```

Nevertheless the transaction is well listed on listtransactions:

```
$  bitcoin-cli -regtest -rpcuser=bitcoinrpc -rpcpassword=Alice -rpcport=16591 listtransactions
...
    {
        "account" : "",
        "address" : "mjeoXvBnD4DtZumeSJEjNJfLb4RrhpbH1H",
        "category" : "send",
        "amount" : -5.00000000,
        "vout" : 1,
        "fee" : -0.00001860,
        "confirmations" : 1,
        "blockhash" : "5851b3adfd810480e53fbb5dab1ce4967a50f072a5a7abe054f114839ea3501e",
        "blockindex" : 1,
        "blocktime" : 1452096896,
        "txid" : "9caca4f88c6bf727f6e8599fc1012867561ff7ef34412ef1fc70457fadf08e0b",
        "walletconflicts" : [
        ],
        "time" : 1452096887,
        "timereceived" : 1452096887
    },
...
```

Is there a problem with my address?

I've generated it thanks to [pybitcointools](https://github.com/vbuterin/pybitcointools/blob/master/bitcoin/main.py) , doing:

```
magickey = '111' # regtest mode

priv = random_key()

addr = privkey_to_address(priv, magickey)
```

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getreceivedbyaddress` is only able to show the balance for the addresses in the account: it stores only UTXO for these. The addresses generated with Pybitcointools are not stored in the account (contrary to addresses generated with `getnewaddress`).

To get the balance of any address, a block explorer is needed, which scan ALL UTXOs of the blockchain (like blockexporer.com or blockchain.info).

And for Regtest, it's more complicated since a local server is needed like https://github.com/bitcoin-abe/bitcoin-abe.

Conclusion: I"ve finally switched to Testnet mode, for convenience.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `getreceivedbyaddress` doesn't include unconfirmed transactions. The second parameter is for the minimum number of confirmations.

So either do `getreceivedbyaddress 0`, or do `setgenerate true 6`, and the received by should be correct.

Comment: It's not unconfirmed: you can see in listtransactions: ` "...confirmations" : 1,...`. But I finally solved the riddle. I didn't get properly what `getreceivedbyaddress` was doing in fact.

Comment: Glad you figured it out :)